# Express redirection after fetching endpoint doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to make a tiktok auth on my react website. Following the tiktok api docs I created an epxress server with the oauth endpoint :

```js
app.get("/oauth", (req, res) => {
    const csrfState = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    res.cookie("csrfState", csrfState, { maxAge: 60000 });

    let url = "https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/";

    url += `?client_key=${CLIENT_KEY}`;
    url += "&scope=user.info.basic,video.list";
    url += "&response_type=code";
    url += `&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}`;
    url += `&state=${csrfState}`;
    
    res.redirect(url);
});
```

which should redirect the user to the tiktok login page :/ Here is the button component in my react frontend :

```js
const TiktokLogin = ({ cssClass }) => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log("Log in");
        fetch("/oauth").then(r => console.log(r))
    };

    return (
        <button type="button" className={cssClass} onClick={handleClick}>
            Identify me with <i className="fab fa-tiktok" />
        </button>
    );
};
```

However when I click on the button, not only I'm not redirected but I get several errors:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/?client_key=xxxx&scope=user.info.basic,video.list&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/signup&state=xxxx' (redirected from 'https://localhost:3000/oauth') from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
GET https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect/?client_key=xxxx&scope=user.info.basic,video.list&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/signup&state=xxxx net::ERR_FAILED
```

In short: I need my button to send the user to /oauth endpoint which should then redirect the user to the tiktok login.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need the user to actually _visit_ the redirected page, not make a fetch request. Use a _link_, not a button.

Comment: `fetch()` calls do NOT cause the browser to redirect.   You just get the 302 response back from the fetch to your Javascript with the redirect URL in the `Location` header.  It's up to your Javascript that ran the `fetch()` call to change the `window.location` if you want the browser to redirect.

Comment: I can't visit the redirected page directly I need to pass through a redirection. Using a Link component to visit the /oauth page doesn't work and returns a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering why `res.redirect(url)` return a 404, it's most likely that you haven't setup a reverse proxy & all the routes are only redirected to the frontend. To solve that, make sure all your backend endpoint have a common base such as /api/xxx and set a reverse proxy for all urls starting with /api